# Reading common food thermometer probes

Tags: sensor, temperature

I have 2 temp probes from a Maverick ET-7 (common on Amazon.com). I would like to setup my Raspberry Pi to read temps from these. I purchased a breadboard and Pi cobbler + cable from Adafruit. Is this possible? Where should I begin? - thanks

EDIT: At this point I am looking to physically connect those generic food temp probes to the Pi. I am not attempting to read the wireless signal from the ET-7.

Comment: might be usefull: http://hackaday.com/2009/01/02/parts-i2c-digital-thermometer-tc74/

Comment: Yes Gerben, thank you. I have some similar sensors to those, but am waiting for resistors to arrive in the mail. I also found another good article on reading the temps and doing something with them: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/temperature/

Comment: Another great example I found from adafruit: http://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing.pdf

I see now that I should have made the title of this to include 'analog food thermometer probes' or something similar. Unfortunately when I search the web for 'digital food thermometer', the results are filled with digital readers of analog probes rather than actual digital probes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those probes are almost certainly analog probes.  The Raspberry Pi does not have any analog inputs so to read the values you will need some sort of Analog to Digital Converter(ADC) that you can connect to the RPi.

You could build one, if you do I would suggest searching for an ADC that has an I2C interface.

You could buy an add-on for the RPi like [this one](http://www.abelectronics.co.uk/products/3/Raspberry-Pi/17/ADC-Pi-V2---Raspberry-Pi-Analogue-to-Digital-converter) which should make things a bit simpler.

Be aware that without the datasheet for the analog probe you will need to manually calibrate your the probe to properly map the analog value to a the temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, most probably you won't be able to read the temperature from these probes without serious hacking. Raspberry Pi won't support their wireless, and does not have ADC converters onboard to allow a direct connection of probes to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I am not talking about using the wireless component of the ET-7. I want to physically connect the probes to the Pi. The probes seem generic to me. I have another, older digital temp and it uses the exact same probe and connector. (search Amazon for 'Maverick ET732 Genuine Replacement 6 Foot Probe').

Comment: Ah, lenkik, had to do some reading. Could I build an ADC converter into a proto-board to connect to the Pi? This is the large gap in my knowledge, the hardware.

Comment: the easiest way might be using usb web-camera to capture and read the temperature off the screen of your temperature monitor. they use 7-seg indicators, should not be too hard to recognize the numbers.